# ruby on rails diff two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two differnt dates in Rails

the current date:

```
DateTime.now
```

and one which is stored in database (belongs to a object)

The format of those two is different:

```
DateTime.now:  2017-06-06T13:06:14+00:00
From Database: 2017-06-06 14:05:00 +0200
```

I want to do a slect like this:

```
@lessons =  self.where("start_date < ? AND active IS NULL", DateTime.now)
```

Problem is that those two dates are different ..

how can I format one of these to the same like the other?

Probably the DateTime.now to the same like one from db?

Comment: What does `Time.zone.now` return?

Comment: You can use the db date with `start_date < now()`

Comment: Formatting is just a representation and does not have a definitive bearing the the ability to use this value in a query. Please remember that you could query like this too `"start_date < '2017-01-01'"` this is perfectly valid even though I am using a String Value here without a time stamp at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert it, rails will take care for you

```
User.where("created_at < ?",  DateTime.now).take
# generate sql 
# SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (created_at < '2017-06-06 13:41:27.649070') LIMIT 1
```